# Flink job on yarn Not starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I have written a simple flink job of word count. I am trying to run the job on yarn and getting the error :

```
2017-10-04 13:15:19,037 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnFlinkResourceManager                - Diagnostics for container ResourceID{resourceId='container_e27_1506324726020_9534_01_000002'} in state COMPLETE : exitStatus=1 diagnostics=Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e27_1506324726020_9534_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:944)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code
```

When i remove  **"logback.xml"** from The configuration directory of flink /hdfs/flink-1.2.1/conf than the same is working fine.

Please help me to understand what is the issue with logback.xml . Not able to understand the cause of problem.

Comment: check if there is any other logback.xml is the jar files which you have imported. A clash of same file names might also cause this.

Comment: I do not have any logback.xml in my jar.